# Sort txt file with JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm making a Scoreboard for a game. I'm developing but have no experience with json.
So far I have made it so it adds a name with a score into a plain text file and also displaying this in game.
Now I want to sort it so that the name with the lowest score goes to the top.

Here is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Score(String gamescore, string loginname)
{
    List<Highscore> Myhighscores = new List<Highscore>();

    string hs = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\hs.txt");
    Myhighscores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Highscore>>(hs);
    Myhighscores.Add(new Highscore { Score = gamescore, Name = loginname });

    string Jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Myhighscores);
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\hs.txt", Jstr);         
}

public void displayScore()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\hs.txt"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<Highscore> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Highscore>>(json);

        foreach (Highscore score in items)
        {
            lblHighscore.Text += $"{score.Name} > {score.Score}  {"Turns"}<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be working.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

p.s Highscore contains 2 public strings called `Name` and `Score`.

Comment: why don't you just use a database? The major pitfall in your current design is that the file will suffer from locking issues if you have more than one process accessing the file at any one time. That's why no body stores things in files directly (anymore)

Comment: Its part of my assignment to use a txt file but i totaly agree with you a database would be 10 times better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty easy all i needed to do is change `gamescore` to a `int` and add the following code:

```
 List<Highscore> SortedList = items.OrderBy(o => o.Score).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your object before writing it again back in file.

```
 Myhighscores.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Score, y.Score));
```

Comment: Just to answer the next question OP will probably be asking: You can limit it to the top-10 scores by adding `.Take(10)`.

Comment: how are you going to sort scores of "1" , "2" and "10" if you are comparing strings?

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns Got me on that one. If the OP wants that, he'll have to write a `delegate` to take this in case. It would be indeed simpler with score stored as `int`.

Comment: `int.TryParse` would basically solve that issue @NoRefundsNoReturns

Comment: Your answer is incorrect given the context of the question.  Consider updating it to use a numeric type for sorting.

Comment: @Liam that's not an answer.

Comment: Not an answer to what @NoRefundsNoReturns? Your comment? Why would I answer a comment?

Comment: @Liam it's not an answer to the original question, it is misleading, it is incomplete and not helpful.  Put it in code format as an answer if you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: @Liam and now you understand why I said it's not an answer.